# Sistema de etiquetas para mensajes creados por usuarios duda sobre como hacer las tablas de la base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, relaciones, modelorelacional

estoy añadiendole funciones a mi pag. web. En este caso quiero crear un sistemas de etiquetas (**#Hashtag**).  Que quedara algo como :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello tengo mi **tabla mensajes**  y mi **tabla etiquetas**:

**Tabla mensajes**

```
Tabla mensajes
      - id
      - titulo
      - contenido
      - createAt
      - url_img
      - creador
```

**Tabla etiquetas**

```
Tabla etiquetas
    - id
    - nombre
```

Claro ahora voy al tema de las relaciones, no se como verlo, tengo dos puntos de vistas y me genera confusion:

A ver **un mensaje** puede tener **varias etiquetas**

Pero claro no es un mensaje son muchos **un mensaje** igual me estoy liando con una tonteria, pero segun a que lo apliques se ve mas facil o no. 

**¿Seria correcto añadir un campo `id_mensaje` a la tabla `etiquetas` y con eso bastaria?**

Que quedaria de la siguiente manera la tabla `etiquetas`:

**Tabla etiquetas**

```
Tabla etiquetas
    - id
    - nombre
    - id_mensaje
```

Comment: debes crear una tabla aparte para etiquetas de mensajes. donde pases el id_mensaje y id_etiquetas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como lo explicas no creo que una etiqueta tenga que estar ligada a los mensajes.

Mencionas que un mensaje puede tener varias etiquetas, pero en el ejemplo que muestras yo pensaría que una misma etiqueta puede estar en varios mensajes. Por lo que la relación seria de varios a varios.

En dicho caso yo crearía una tabla para esa relación:

```
Tabla EtiquetasEnMensajes
 - id del mensaje
 - id de la etiqueta.
```

Así relacionaría esas tablas.

Comment: Lo que pretendo es lo tipico de las redes sociales, que un mensaje ppueda tener muchos `#hashtag` s ciertamente es como tu dices, no habia caido, lo que yo queria hacer obligaba a referenciar un mensaje a los hastag creados, con lo cual, no tenia ningun sentido